# Can’t erase Bootcamp volume to reinstall MacOS

Tags: windows, disk-utility, bootcamp, partition

I had MacOS Monterrey installed and wanted to dual boot with Windows 10. I used BootCamp to install Windows 10 on another partition I created.

Somehow along the way, my macOS partition got completely wiped out.

I don’t see it as a boot up selection when I hold Option during boot up. I only see Windows. I boot up via the Internet Recovery partition and using `diskutil list`, I see the following:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data New Volume              177 GB     disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data Windows                 322 GB     disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme -                      +3.2 GB     disk1
   1:                Apple_HFS macOS Base System         2.9 GB     disk1s1
```

I ran `diskutil cs list` which shows:

```
No CoreStorage logical volume groups found
```

I have tried to perform the following command but I get a `Error: -69878: Couldn’t open disk`:

```
diskutil eraseVolume free none disk0s3
```

I want to start over from scratch and have Monterrey re-installed with Bootcamp deleted. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you should use the instructions posted at the Apple website [How to reinstall macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904). If you follow the posted instructions and are still having problems, then update your question. Be sure to describe what you did so far and what the new problems you are having.

A couple of helpful comments are given below.

- You should use Option-Command-R during startup to be offered either the latest macOS that is compatible with your Mac, or in some cases the macOS that came with your Mac or the closest version still available.
- You will need to need to [erase your disk](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208496) before installing macOS.

BTW, Monterey must be installed on APFS (Apple File System) volumes. APFS has replaced legacy Core Storage. In  you question, you entered `diskutil cs list`. Under Monterey, the equivalent command would be `diskutil apfs list`.